# ng-bootstrap accordion panel color change

Tags: angular, accordion, ng-bootstrap

I am using ng-bootstrap accordion. I need to show the header of panels in ngb-accordion if it have error. Since I am having form inside ngb-accordion.

I have a form and I used ngb-accordion to split my form in to 2 parts.
Suppose 
**first panel (ngb-panel) contains contact details** and 
**second panel contains educational details**.

If fields under first panel have error its header color need to change to red.
Since the DOM elements for header are created when showing the UI. I am not able to change the color dynamically.

```
<form>
    <ngb-accordion #acc="ngbAccordion" [closeOthers]="true">
                <ngb-panel title="First Panel" [id]="firstPanel" [ngclass]="haveErrror: firstPanelHaveError">
                    <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
                    ............Contact Details..................
                    </ng-template>
                </ngb-panel>
                <ngb-panel title="Second Panel" [id]="secondPanel" [ngclass]="haveErrror: secondPanelHaveError">
                    <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
                    ..............Educational Details................
                    </ng-template>
                </ngb-panel>
    </ngb-accordion>
</form>
```

Rendered content

```
<form>
   <div class="card">
       <div role="tab" id="[object Object]-header" class="card-header active">
         <a href="" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="[object Object]" aria-disabled="false">First Panel</a>
       </div>

        ....................... 
        --Other Contents---
        ........................
        ............................ 
  </div>
```

Can anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 1):

you can access to ngb-accordion style through deep.

For example, you can add this in your CSS file to change the title

```
/deep/ ngb-accordion{

  .btn-link{
    margin-bottom: 0;
    color: #656565;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    font-weight: normal;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-decoration: none!important;

  }

 .btn-link:hover{
     color: #df5329;
     font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none!important;
  }
}
```